# Remove all instances of substring between two substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string of the following type:

```
original = '''{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POSTNR_TXT": "2740", "POSTBYNAVN": "Skovlunde", "POSTNR_FRA": "2740", "POSTNR_TIL": "2740" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 12.370879248624883, 55.702694453782499, -999.0 ], [ 12.368759608893962, 55.712782195962298, -999.0 ], [ 12.37592021897154, 55.714470717642058, -999.0 ], [ 12.379768987708616, 55.72179157095912, -999.0 ], [ 12.387458937414024, 55.697314488019053, -999.0 ], [ 12.370879248624883, 55.702694453782499, -999.0 ] ] ] } }, 
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POSTNR_TXT": "2760", "POSTBYNAVN": "Måløv", "POSTNR_FRA": "2760", "POSTNR_TIL": "2760" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 12.263563465104953, 55.747721989578324, -999.0 ], [ 12.269722469884702, 55.755314897874221, -999.0 ], [ 12.269036118830314, 55.757243692362579, -999.0 ], [ 12.265194268837073, 55.747241588321643, -999.0 ], [ 12.263563465104953, 55.747721989578324, -999.0 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POSTNR_TXT": "2770", "POSTBYNAVN": "Kastrup", "POSTNR_FRA": "2770", "POSTNR_TIL": "2770" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 12.648007056263456, 55.646479764886891, -999.0 ], [ 12.647861947597349, 55.646179791784299, -999.0 ], [ 12.648845856031999, 55.644280146846299, -999.0 ], [ 12.627212246529135, 55.641560131234343, -999.0 ], [ 12.648007056263456, 55.646479764886891, -999.0 ] ] ] } },
```

I want to remove the substring from "POSTBYNAVN": to "POSTNR_TIL": so that my new string is like this:

```
new = '''{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POSTNR_TXT": "2740", "2740" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 12.370879248624883, 55.702694453782499, -999.0 ], [ 12.368759608893962, 55.712782195962298, -999.0 ], [ 12.37592021897154, 55.714470717642058, -999.0 ], [ 12.379768987708616, 55.72179157095912, -999.0 ], [ 12.387458937414024, 55.697314488019053, -999.0 ], [ 12.370879248624883, 55.702694453782499, -999.0 ] ] ] } }, 
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POSTNR_TXT": "2760", "2760" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 12.263563465104953, 55.747721989578324, -999.0 ], [ 12.269722469884702, 55.755314897874221, -999.0 ], [ 12.269036118830314, 55.757243692362579, -999.0 ], [ 12.265194268837073, 55.747241588321643, -999.0 ], [ 12.263563465104953, 55.747721989578324, -999.0 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "POSTNR_TXT": "2770", "2770" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 12.648007056263456, 55.646479764886891, -999.0 ], [ 12.647861947597349, 55.646179791784299, -999.0 ], [ 12.648845856031999, 55.644280146846299, -999.0 ], [ 12.627212246529135, 55.641560131234343, -999.0 ], [ 12.648007056263456, 55.646479764886891, -999.0 ] ] ] } },
```

I've thought about a few solutions but they only affect the first instance. I'm thinking I need some kind of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for python2 and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for python3. Now I will write a posible solution, but you should read befor use it.

```
re.sub('POSTBYNAVN.*?POSTNR_TIL', '', original)
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets rid of every `POSTBYNAVN` part. I think You can figure out the rest by yourself. Cheers.

```
re.sub('\"POSTBYNAVN\":\s\"[a-zA-z]+\"\,\s', '', original)
```

EDIT:

Unfortunately this one doesn't match `"POSTBYNAVN": "M\xc3\xa5l\xc3\xb8v"` because it contains special symbols, so I have changed the regex to:

```
re.sub('\"POSTBYNAVN\":\s\"([^\s]+)\s', '', original)
```

`([^\s]+)` matches any word until first space and now it works as intended.
However the final solution doesn't even use this and looks like this:

```
re.sub('\"POSTBYNAVN.*?POSTNR_TIL\":\s', '', original)
```